# Unable to display Gridx from JSON data

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have written a simple program to fetch data from an external `JSON` file and display it in `Dojo Gridx`. However, it is not working.

**Dojo Code:**

```
require(["dojo/text!json_to_gridx/js/data.json", "dojo/json", "gridx/Grid"], function(myJSONData, JSON, Gridx) {

    // fetch and parse JSON
    var myJSON = JSON.parse(myJSONData);
    console.log(myJSON);    // working fine

    // create datastore
    var store = myJSON;     // should this be changed?

    // create Gridx
    if(!window.grid){
        console.log('working');     // working fine
        gridx = new Gridx({
                    id: 'grid',
                    store: store,
                    structure: [
                        {id: 'name', field: 'name', name: 'Name'},
                        {id: 'company', field: 'company', name: 'Company'}
                    ]
        });
        console.log('working2');   // does not work
        gridx.placeAt('gridContainer');
        gridx.startup();
    }

});
```

**JSON:**

```
[{"name": "Rahul Desai","company": "PSL"},{"name": "Alston","company": "PSL"}]
```

**I am getting an error:**

```
TypeError: cacheClass is not a constructor            Model.js
```

How do I fix this? Please help!

**EDIT:** I was being suggested to use `Memory Store` and `"gridx/core/model/cache/Async"`
Now, the code for creating the Gridx looks like:

```
this._disksGrid = new Gridx({
    id: 'grid',
    cacheClass: asyncCache,
    store: store,
    structure: [
        {id: 'name', field: 'name', name: 'Name'},
        {id: 'company', field: 'company', name: 'Company'}
    ]
});
```

No error now, but the Gridx is not displayed. Any idea why?

**EDIT 2:** Turns out I was starting wrong grid in previous edit. Now the Gridx shows up but the second value is repeated and the first value does now show up.

```
Name   Company
Alston  PSL
Alston  PSL
```

Comment: Good job!!. I forgot to add cacheClass: asyncCache in my grid. You made my day!! Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the changes mentioned in EDIT and EDIT 2 and also added unique IDs to every row of JSON and validated it correctly. That solved the problem.